# how to customize video view of android

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to customize video view of android , Custom video view should be look like given pic.[image: video view]

the seek bar is look like

[image: Seek bar]

please help me.    thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to more customize the video, you have to write your own native library. Otherwise you can use MediaMetadataRetriver class to extract frame by frame.
[Take a look](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

Comment: Download Gingerbread source code and have a look media_jni native library source at ANDROID_GINGERBRD_2.3.4_\WORKING_DIRECTORY\frameworks\base\media\jni. Media_jni library is the entry library for media. Before handling it you have to understand the overview of media framework. At first configure your eclipse with native support(with android ndk). Use the native library source in your project and make your own library. This is not too much easy. Use your own native in the media java source(ANDROID_GINGERBRD_2.3.4_\WORKING_DIRECTORY\frameworks\base\media\java\android\media)

Answer (score 0):

Apart frame by frame display. you can do rest of the things like seek bar, video layout, overlays on video, etc.